# Define delimiter for mysql in terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, applescript

I'm running some Mysql queries in Terminal or using a shell script via AppleScript and it spits out it's results as a \t "tab" delimiter. Is there a way to change this somehow?

Here's an example of what I run:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -e "SELECT * FROM mysql.table_name LIMIT 1;"
```

or Applescript:

```
set blah to (do shell script "/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -e \"SELECT * FROM mysql.table_name LIMIT 1;\""
```

Now the variable 'blah' is my returned result and then I can use AppleScript's text item delimiters to read the text and get a specific text item I want...

My data is stored with the "|" field delimiter but for some reason it show "\t" when I run this

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm curious why you say your data is already pipe delimited, is it based on what you see in the terminal when you run your sql command? The data in the database isn't set to any specific delimiter, the display you're seeing in the terminal is just that, a display.

In any event, you're correct. When you run the select statement in your applescript it will give you the data as tab delimited. You also have a valid concern about if your data already contains a tab. The good news is the two tabs are handled differently. The delimiter between your fields is returned as a tab (in other words **\t**), but the tab inside your content will be returned as an escaped tab (in other words **\\t**). So you can rest easy knowing that if you use the text item delimiters set to tab, you will in fact break your content the way you expect.

Comment: Well this does help. The reason I was saying I have it stored as a pipe is only because that's how I import and export as a .csv so I know that there are NO vertical bars in my data. But I guess you are correct about how the data is stored. There is one thing though.. When I want to select just one column and it returns one result, then it is delimited with a line feed or carriage return "\n" or "\r" because of the fact it gives me one header and one result. Any ideas?

Comment: I do this process a lot myself. When I retrieve the data, I always do a test to see if it is blank, if so, that means I found nothing, if not, I always first delimit the results by the return character and set a results variable to items 2 thru -1 of. This gives me an item for each record. I then loop the records and delimit them by the tab to get the individual fields. I hope this is what you're looking for. If I've misunderstood, let me know and I can see if I can clarify.

Comment: I think I understand. Basically minus out the headers and see if there is a result. Then if so, use the "\t" as your text item delimiters to read the fields of your data.

Comment: Yes, with the exception of seeing if there is a result first, then if there is, minus the headers.

Answer (score 0):

rather than change the output of the mysql query you can just change applescripts text item delimiters like so

```
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tab
-- do stuff
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
```

if the tab is coming in as literal text "\t" then

```
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "\t"
-- do stuff
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid
```

Comment: This is true, and I have been doing this, but what if there is a tab in my data... I know that all fields are delimited by a "|" so if I use that, then there is no chance in error.